# Error while installing OSDE package in Eclipse helios

Tags: eclipse, opensocial, helios

I am trying to install Opensocial plugin in Eclipse Helios as per installation guide in the link http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-development-environment/wiki/InstallationGuide , but getting following error.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, 
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Error closing the output stream for osgi.bundle,com.googlecode.osde,1.0.0 on repository 
file:/C:/eclipse3.6/.
Error unzipping C:\Users\NISHU~1.TAY\AppData\Local
\Temp\com.googlecode.osde_1.0.02564973307123246955.jar: Invalid zip file format
```

How can i get rid of this error?

Comment: Have you looked at the downloaded jar file to see if it looks like it downloaded correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the repository that points to file:/C:/eclipse3.6/ in the **Available Software Sites** (under Preferences -> Install/Update).

After you delete it, you can put the address: *http://opensocial-development-environment.googlecode.com/svn/update-site/site.xml* in the **Work with:** url and press Enter.

If it doesn't work (it didn't work for me, but it could be because of the lousy internet connection here), you can always download the jars and put them under c:/eclipse3.6/plugins.